# Custom Category Attribute - Adding 'insert images' button

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I've created a new category text area attribute called featcms.  In my custom module category_form.xml I have;

```
<field name="featcms" template="ui/form/field" sortOrder="13" formElement="wysiwyg">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="settings" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="theme_advanced_buttons1" xsi:type="string">bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,|,code</item>
                    <item name="theme_advanced_buttons2" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="theme_advanced_buttons3" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="theme_advanced_buttons4" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="theme_advanced_statusbar_location" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
                <item name="files_browser_window_url" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Featured CMS Small Squares</label>
        <dataScope>featcms</dataScope>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <wysiwyg class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg">
            <settings>
                <rows>8</rows>
                <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
            </settings>
        </wysiwyg>
    </formElements>
</field>
```

As you can see I've added 3 buttons - add variables, add widget and add image.  The insert variable and insert widget buttons work fine, but when I click the 'insert image...' button, the popup loads and an ajax call is made and succeeds;

```
[domain/admin]/catalog/category/edit/id/5307/target_element_id/category_form_featcms/?isAjax=true
```

But the call responds with json only and nothing renders in the popup - we should be expecting the image upload form here.

I notice when you scrutinise the CMS page 'insert image' button, the ajax url fired is;

```
[domain/admin]/cms/wysiwyg_images/index/target_element_id/cms_page_form_content/?isAjax=true
```

So appears to hit a cms/wysiwyg_images specific end point.  Do we need to replicate this path for a category attribute?   and if so how should this be set in the category_form xml.

Thanks

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: I'm struggling with almost the same problem just for the Magento standard attribute `description`. At `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml` the item for `files_browser_window_url` is set to boolean `false`. So is there any chance to remove that item from that source config? Setting the value to `true` is not working according to the Daniels answer.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/157877)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just facing the same problem. The solution lays in the config key `files_browser_window_url` you pass. You just need to remove

```
 <item name="files_browser_window_url" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```

and it should work.

In \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Editor the method `_getPluginButtonsHtml()` gets called and sets the `onclick` event value for the "Insert Image" button.

Within this string `$this->getConfig('files_browser_window_url')` is called and in your case it's "true" so it adds "true" to the url and breaks it with it.

So this field in you xml should work:

```
<field name="featcms" template="ui/form/field" sortOrder="13" formElement="wysiwyg">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="settings" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="theme_advanced_buttons1" xsi:type="string">bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,|,code</item>
                    <item name="theme_advanced_buttons2" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="theme_advanced_buttons3" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="theme_advanced_buttons4" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="theme_advanced_statusbar_location" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
                <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Featured CMS Small Squares</label>
        <dataScope>featcms</dataScope>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <wysiwyg class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg">
            <settings>
                <rows>8</rows>
                <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
            </settings>
        </wysiwyg>
    </formElements>
</field>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found workable variant in Magento_Cms module in cms_page_form ui component:

```
<field name="custom_field" formElement="wysiwyg">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <additionalClasses>
            <class name="admin__field-wide">true</class>
        </additionalClasses>
        <label/>
        <dataScope>custom_field</dataScope>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <wysiwyg>
            <settings>
                <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
            </settings>
        </wysiwyg>
    </formElements>
</field>
```

Comment: Hi, this doesnt work in a category context